# UIPageControl equivalent in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, uipagecontrol

i am working on porting an iphone application to blackberry devices. 
i could not find any equivalent of UIPagecontrol in Blackberry. 
Actually, any ideas to making similar of UIPageControl is enough for me.

Comment: UIPageControl is not a self-explanatory name.  What does it do?

Comment: its look like jquery image sliders (content slider... etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct equivilent.  The closest native control would probably be a tabbed Pane Manager. Or you could just write your own custom control to mimic the iPhone behavior.

Comment: i have restrictions like using 4.5 JDE. But you give me an idea. i found this article; [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Focus-Gained-issue-with-quot-tabbed-view-screens-page-quot/td-p/274788). <br/> i am on holiday now but after the holiday i will check is it fit for me ?